# VSTS - MVC Web app deploy task is deprecated. How to deploy to test server on prem

Tags: azure-devops

Setting up a Release definition task to deploy a MVC web app to a test server (on prem).  Typically I have done this a FileSystem publish via a Visual Studio publish profile.  What task can I use in VSTS to achieve the same thing, assuming I already have a working agent setup on the test server and a successful build?

The app is actually setup as a website on the test server, not a virtual app under another website.  Looking at adding the "IIS Web App Deploy" task, VSTS reports that this task is "deprecated, so what is the suggested replacement for this?

I suppose I could use the [Windows file copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts), but the build artifacts are zipped.  What would I need to use if I went this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Visual Studio Build task** with `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish` **MSBuild Arguments** to publish web app to artifact folder (e.g. `{agent working folder}/1/a`).

You also can specify the publish profile directly `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="{publish profile name}";publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"`

With **FileSystem publish** method, the published files are in a folder, not zipped, but you can zipped the folder through **Archive files** task.

Also you can extract files through **Extract files** task, so you can copy extracted files through Window machine file copy task to the corresponding web site path.

On the other hand, you can deploy the web app through [WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploy/README_IISAppDeploy.md).

Comment: Wont I need Visual Studio installed on the on-prem server where the release agent is located for this?

Comment: @bitshift Just install [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) on build/release agent.